# MPMoviePlayerController in background doesn't leave page when we change scene

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a video in the background of a `CCMenu`. So I have a video playing behind some buttons. When I switch views/scenes, I want the `moviePlayer` to leave the scene the same as the buttons/images on that layer/scene.

The code to play the movie in the background is as follows:

```
-(void)playMainMenuVideo{
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MYMMainMenu" ofType:@"mov"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController * player=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[[player view] setFrame:[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] bounds]];
player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] addSubview:[player view]];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]view] sendSubviewToBack:player.view];
UIView* glView = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view; // attention
[glView.superview insertSubview:player.view atIndex:0]; // attention
glView.opaque = NO; // attention
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // attention
}
```

This works perfect, In the app delegate I also changed

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565 // To kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
```

Lastly I want to do a page turn like so:

```
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [CCTransitionPageTurn transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[FirstPageViewController scene]]];
```

But only the sprites will leave the scene, the video stays playing in the background. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

1) Setup notification for when video is done playing. 
2) When its done playing, place an image of the last frame of the video, over the video. 
3) Then set these properties back to original

```
UIView* glView = [CCDirector sharedDirector].view; // attention
glView.opaque = YES; // attention
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

4)Remove `MPMoviePlayerController`

Happy Coding everyone :)